# Make an AS3/Flex class Extendable but not Instantiatable as an object?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a class `SuperClass` that implements an interface, and has all the public methods of the interface implemented. I have another class `SubClass` that extends `SuperClass`. I dont want those public methods being used incorrectly. This leads to my question:

How do I prevent `SuperClass` from ever being instantiated as an object?

Brian

**Update: Using hint from answer below, solution is:**

```
public function MyClass():void
{           
     if(getQualifiedClassName(this) == "ui.controls::MyClass")
     {
         throw new Error('MyClass is an abstract class, do ' +
                                    'not instantiate');
     }           

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS3 does not support abstract classes. The best you can do is runtime enforcement. Check out [this post](http://joshblog.net/2007/08/19/enforcing-abstract-classes-at-runtime-in-actionscript-3/) for more info.